# Socket.io callback is not a function error

Tags: express, socket.io

I was trying to use callbacks in my socket.io application but for some reason, it doesn't accept my callback function and throws an error with message `TypeError: callback is not a function`. I don't know why my application throws this error. I compare my code with socket.io's documentation on *Socket.io Acknowledgements*. They look the same but somehow my code is not working. Can you spot the problem, please?

This is the example code from Socket.io's documentation on *acknowledgements (callbacks)*:

[image: Socket.io documentation]

My current code on server side:

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    debug(`${socket.id} connected!`);

    socket.on('player joined', (player, callback) => {
        players.push(player);
        io.emit('update', players);
        callback(true);
    });
});
```

My current code on client side:

```js
socket.emit('player joined', player, (isClientReady) => {
    if(isClientReady) {
        lastRender = 0;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
});
```

Error thrown out by my server side code:

[image: Error log]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you receiving `player` argument or it's just the callback problem?

Comment: @omidh Oh my! I just added a ``console.log(player);`` to check if I get the player parameter correctly and it didn't throw error. I removed ``console.log(player);`` line and checked out again, it didn't throw error again. I tried few things before posting question here, I check out some resources that can help me solve the question and It suddenly solved out by itself. Something wrong with me...

Comment: It's alright :D

Comment: @omidh anyways still thanks for checking my question. Have a good day :P

Comment: are you creating any kind of wrapper around socket?  make sure it lines up.   I have a wrapper and fixed this problem in my `emit` method with:

`emit: function (event, data, fn) {
    this.socket.emit(event, data, res => fn(res))
  }`

Comment: @omidh there is nothing wrong in you :) it's only the more often issue called pebcak, like my logo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (typeof callback === "function") callback(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, your code is pretty fine, the reason why your server is throwing "callback is not a function"
is because you need to ensure you're sending a payload or data through the emit function from the client-side.

What i meant is, if you perform the callback function call and no data, payload, body etc is received or it is undefined , then Javascript won't be able to recognize the callback function from the server-side.

Probably, the player argument is undefined or you misspelled a word.

```
socket.emit('player joined', player, (isClientReady) => {
    if(isClientReady) {
        lastRender = 0;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason, not related to your code, but that will cause the same error, is the missing second parameter (the value).

Server side:

```
socket.emit("eventName", new JSONObject(singletonMap("name", "updated")), (Ack) ackArgs -> {
    JSONObject response = (JSONObject) ackArgs[0];
    try {
        System.out.println("eventName ack resp: " + response.getString("status")); // "ok"
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('eventName', async (msg, clientOffset, callback) => {
    callback({
        status: "ok"
    });
});
```

By adding it, the issue is solved:

`socket.emit("eventName"`**`, "eventValue"`**`, new JSONObject(singletonMap(...`